# How to open a file in Microsoft Visio in command line?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-visio

I am trying to open a file in Microsoft Visio using command line. `start \d "path" visio.exe`

Now, how to open a specific file? `\1` opens first previously opened file, but not the specific one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples:
`start "C:\complete\path\to\file.vsd"`
or
`cd /d "C:\complete\path\to\" & start "file.vsd"`

i.e. if the file type is associated to visio, it will open in visio.

Comment: `cd /d "C:\complete\path\to\" & start file.vsd` start followed by filename without double quotes worked

Comment: The quotes is a "safeguard" against space characters in the path and filename, very strange if it doesn't work with them.